# Error when updating to Ubuntu 23.04 from 22.10

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 23.04

I am getting the following error when attempting to upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04

```
Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, 
W:Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, 
W:Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, 
W:Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target Translations 
(main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times 
in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times 
in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target DEP-11-icons 
(main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is 
configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is 
configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target Packages 
(restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, 
W:Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target Translations 
(restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target DEP-11 
(restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times 
in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple 
times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, 
W:Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is 
configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target DEP-11-icons 
(restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target 
DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured 
multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:40 and 
/etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target CNF 
(restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, W:Target CNF 
(restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:40 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54, E:The 
repository 'https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu 
kinetic Release' does not have a Release file. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: As the error messages say, look in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the duplicate lines.

Comment: Please check your sources list, there seem to be duplicates entries in there. Especially around line 54 and 40. Maybe you could post your sources.list?